# Modify global list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a couple lists that I create, one example being:

```
onButtonVal = [0] * 8
onButtonVal = [0 for i in xrange(8)]
```

and then a modify function:

```
def buttonSelectOn(outlet):

    global onButtonVal

    if outlet == 1:
        onButtonVal[0] = 1
```

and I try to access it in another function:

```
def applySettings(outlet):

    if outlet == 1:
        if onButtonVal[0] == 1:
            turnOnOutlet(1)
```

When I try to do all this, I get `TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment`

What am I doing wrong? I just want to create a simple array/list of 8 ints and be able to modify it in one function and access it in others

Comment: Your error is in `turnOnOutlet` function (which you haven't included).

Comment: That function only sends an snmp command based on which outlet is being turned on/off, it doesn't use the list at all

Comment: And on a side note, the 2nd assignment (`onButtonVal = [0 for i in xrange(8)]`) is redundant

Comment: I think you assigned an integer to `onButtonVal` itself somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Another option is that global `onButtonVal` in `buttonSelectOn` is an integer and not a list. Please provide [MCVE] that expose your issue.

Comment: Always include the full traceback!  Being able to see what lines are relevant in the error is extremely helpful to people who can help you.